# Why can't one cancel partial differentials?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, chain-rule

I have a question about the below formula:

> $$\frac{dz}{ds} = \frac{dz}{dx} \cdot \frac{dx}{ds} + \frac{dz}{dy} \cdot \frac{dy}{ds}$$

Ok. I understand what this means. Small change of s makes small change of x and y and thus the sum makes small change of z.

However, I simply can't understand the formula itself.

> $$2\cdot\frac{dz}{ds} = \frac{dz}{dx} \cdot \frac{dx}{ds} + \frac{dz}{dy} \cdot \frac{dy}{ds}$$

Why not this? Every book I have read defines calculus by multiplication and division. Then it must be $2\cdot\frac{dz}{ds}$ I think. Is there anything I missed?

edit: z= z(x,y), x=x(s,t), y=y(s,t)

Comment: How are $x$, $y$, and $z$ related?

Comment: They’re not actual fractions, you can’t cancel the way you seem to be thinking. It is just an unfortunate side effect of the notation that what you wrote looks plausible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing the formula like this is wrong for $z\equiv z(x,y), x\equiv x(s,t), y\equiv y(s,t)$

One should write it using [partial derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20partial%20derivative,variables%20are%20allowed%20to%20vary).
\begin{align*}
dz &= \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}dx+ \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}dy\\
dz &= \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial  s}ds+\frac{\partial x}{\partial  t}dt \right)+ \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial s}ds+\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}dt\right)\tag{1}\\
\frac{\partial z}{\partial s} &= \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial  s}+ \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial s}\right)ds+\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial  t}+ \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}\right)dt\\
\frac{\partial z}{\partial s} &= \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial  s}+ \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial s}\tag{2}\\
\end{align*}
If it were $z\equiv z(x,y), x\equiv x(s), y\equiv y(s)$, then it would have become
\begin{align*}
dz &= \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{ds}ds+ \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{ds}ds\\
\frac{dz}{ds} &= \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{ds}+ \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{ds}\\
\end{align*}
If it were $z\equiv z(x), x\equiv x(s,t)$, then it would have become
\begin{align*}
dz &= \frac{dz}{dx}\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial  s}ds+\frac{\partial x}{\partial  t}dt \right)\\
\frac{\partial z}{\partial s} &= \frac{dz}{d
x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial  s}\\
\end{align*}
If it were $z\equiv z(x), x\equiv x(t)$, then it would have become
\begin{align*}
dz &= \frac{dz}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}dt\\
\frac{dz}{dt} &= \frac{dz}{d
x}\frac{dx}{dt}\tag{3}\\
\end{align*}
This is why one can write $a=\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{dv}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}=v\frac{dv}{dx}$ in a one-dimensional mechanics problem. Here, $dx$ seem to cancel but what is going on is equation $(3)$.

---

This *apparent* cancellation doesn't take place on partial differential $\partial x$ as in equation $(2)$. For example: In polar coordinates, $x\equiv x(r,\theta)=r\cos\theta,y\equiv y(r,\theta)=r\sin\theta,r\equiv r(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2},\theta\equiv\theta(x,y)=\tan^{-1}\frac yx$

- $\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}=\cos\theta$ if one takes $r,\theta$ as independent variables.
- $\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}=\cos\theta$ if one takes $x,y$ as independent variables.

Clearly, $\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\neq1$ generally.

---

### Takeaway: Always start with equations like equation $(1)$ taking into account all the dependencies of all the variables.

Comment: Thanks for wonderful answer!